# Embed Bitmap Image into Excel merged cell using Shapes.AddPicture method

Tags: excel, bitmapimage

I am looking to embed a Bitmap image into a merged cell in Excel. I have used the .Picture.Insert method but I want to use the Shapes.AddPicture method to preserve the image in the Excel file for sending to various recipients outside the office/network. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture  tells you what you need to do.  If you have existing code which has problems, you should post it.  If you *don't* have code, it's usually best to try writing some beforep osting.